# jquery too much recursion on multiple blur function

Tags: jquery

I am checking some textboxes on blur, some need to be checked against the same critera so I put these all in one blur function. I have noticed that my page seems slow and in firebug I keep gettin the error `too much recursion` .

My code is below, it checks the textbox and then sends the ID to another function which adds a class to say if it is valid or not valid.

```
$('#username, #customerName, #customerTown, #customerCounty, #contactName, #staffFirstname, #staffLastname, #staffTown, #staffCounty').blur(function()
{
   var ID = $(this).attr('id');
       var val = $(this).val();                     
       if(validate(val))
       {
           valid(ID);

       }
       else
       {            
           notValid(ID);
       }

});

function valid(elementID)
{
            $('#'+elementID+'Img').html('<img src="../images/tick.png" alt="Valid" title="Valid" />');
            $('#' + elementID).addClass('valid');

}

function notValid(elementID)
{
            $('#'+elementID+'Img').html('<img src="../images/cross.png" alt="Not Valid" title="Not Valid" />');
            $('#' + elementID).removeClass('valid');                    

}

function validate(val)
    {
        var reg = new RegExp ("^([a-zA-Z ]){3,90}$");
        var regTest = reg.test(val); 
        if(regTest)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
             return false;
        }
}
```

Would it be better if I did a seprate `blur` function for each textbox? Or is there another way? I don't really want to write a blur function for every single textbox.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it's this code that causes the slowness and the error messages? I find nothing that would be slow and no recursion.

Comment: Thats basically all the code I have on my page, theres a few more text boxes which are checked but its in the same way as above. Only other function is a onclick but I get the error before it is pressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your code, and it doesn't show any signs of slowness, and there is no error messages at all, not even in the error console.

http://jsfiddle.net/5sFWF/

Here are some suggested changes in the code, using a single function to set the status instead of two, using jQuery to create elements instead of pasting together HTML code, avoiding the *if-true-then-true-else-false* antipattern in the validate function:

http://jsfiddle.net/5sFWF/2/